# How can I get specific data from a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api

I'm trying to make a web application about movies with a movie API. Then I copied first two parts of search results and stored them in a variable; how can I get the specific data from variable?

I've considered like the JSON file is an object and tried to get the specific data but I couldn't.

This is the first two parts of search results that I stored in a variable.

```
  var searchResults = {
    page: 1,
    total_results: 4109,
    total_pages: 206,
    results: [
      {
        original_name: 'Star',
        id: 68780,
        media_type: 'tv',
        name: 'Star',
        vote_count: 62,
        vote_average: 7.12,
        first_air_date: '2016-12-14',
        popularity: 16.022,
        original_language: 'en',
      },
      {
        original_name: '부암동 복수자들',
        id: 74473,
        media_type: 'tv',
        name: 'Avengers Social Club',
        vote_count: 4,
        vote_average: 9,
        first_air_date: '2017-10-11',
        popularity: 1.668,
        original_language: 'ko',
      }]};
```

I want to see names of this movies in console. How can I see names of this two movies in console.

I have tried this:

```
var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'api.themoviedb.org/3/search/multi',
    qs: {
        include_adult: 'false', page: '1',
        query: 'star', language: 'en-US', api_key: 'I CANT SHOW THIS'
    }, body: '{}'
};
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("ERROR!");
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body); 
            console.log(parsedBody["results"][0].name);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? What happened?

Comment: @SLaks var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body); console.log(parsedBody["results"][0].name); But I got undefined.

Comment: That should work.  What is `parsedBody`?

Comment: var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/multi',
  qs: 
   { include_adult: 'false',
     page: '1',
     query: 'star',
     language: 'en-US',
     api_key: 'I CANT SHOW THIS' },
  body: '{}' };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if(error){
      console.log("ERROR!");
      console.log(error);
  }else{
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(parsedBody["results"][0].name);
      }
  }
});

Comment: @Güney Please console log the `parsedBody` and add it to the question. or console log the `body` and add it to the question.

Comment: "request" is undefined there. How are you getting that JSON back with that request?

Comment: @Bman70 I defined request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how many results are returned in each JSON response, you can loop this way using a results count. For the two results in your example, it loops as long as `i <  2`:

```js
var searchResults = {
    page: 1,
    total_results: 4109,
    total_pages: 206,
    results: [
      {
        original_name: 'Star',
        id: 68780,
        media_type: 'tv',
        name: 'Star',
        vote_count: 62,
        vote_average: 7.12,
        first_air_date: '2016-12-14',
        popularity: 16.022,
        original_language: 'en',
      },
      {
        original_name: '부암동 복수자들',
        id: 74473,
        media_type: 'tv',
        name: 'Avengers Social Club',
        vote_count: 4,
        vote_average: 9,
        first_air_date: '2017-10-11',
        popularity: 1.668,
        original_language: 'ko',
      }]};  

    for (var i=0; i < 2; i++) {
    console.log(searchResults['results'][i].name);
        }
```